# Nginx user account used for web directory on EC2 with Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have setup Nginx on Amazon Linux AMI. The default Nginx page loads fine:

```
http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

and the server statement code in nginx.conf is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    #server_name  localhost;
    server_name ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

So tested it with my domain by changing the server_name to

```
server_name samplesite.com;
```

it also works fine by accessing using the browser

```
http://samplesite.com/
```

But when I changed the "location / root" to a different path, it doesn't work, and here is the nginx.conf server statement:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name samplesite.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /home/ec2-user/samplesite.com/public_html; <--- Changed here!!!
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The only part that was changed is

```
root /home/ec2-user/samplesite.com/public_html;
```

It's because I wanted the site directory to be located under "ec2-user". I checked the default Nginx directory file owner at

```
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

but everything is owned by "root" which as I know it's not recommended use root account and should use a different user account:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 22 01:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 22 01:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3696 Nov 21 22:04 404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3738 Nov 21 22:04 50x.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3770 Nov 21 22:04 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  370 Nov 21 22:04 nginx-logo.png
```

so wanted to use "ec2-user" instead (or should I create a new account for web?). So my question is, is the directory must be owned by "root" to work? Because I can't seem to make the website accessible if the directory owner is "ec2-user" under the `/home/` directory.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant part from your access log? What euid is your nginx running under?

Comment: Nginx is run as nginx user

Answer (score 10):

Make sure `/home/ec2-user/samplesite.com/public_html` has 755 permissions.

Another way to make it work is to run the nginx worker process as `ec2-user`. In the nginx.conf file with something like this:

```
user              ec2-user;
worker_processes  1;
```

Make sure everythin under `/home/ec2-user/samplesite.com/public_html` has the owner.group `ec2-user`

```
chown -R ec2-user.ec2-user /home/ec2-user/samplesite.com/public_html
```

Hope it helps.